# How did the JAXA lunar probe discover that there is a 50 km long cave on the Moon?

Tags: the-moon, caves

Breaking Space news! I just heard a short item on the BBC news broadcast (ok, podcast). It said that a JAXA lunar orbiter has determined that a previously identified cave is quite extensive - perhaps 50 km long!

What spacecraft could they be talking about, and how does a spacecraft determine the length of sub-surface caves?

So far I've only found holes. See for example [LRO Takes a Closer Look at Moon Caves](https://www.universetoday.com/73659/lro-takes-closer-look-at-moon-caves/) and also [Russia Eyes Caves on Moon for Setting Up a Lunar Base](https://www.universetoday.com/90031/russia-eyes-caves-on-moon-for-setting-up-a-lunar-base/) where dimensions of 50 to 400 *meters* (not kilometers) are mentioned.

**edit:** I have found a ~50 km collapsed cave identified by surface features in this [NASA LRO page](https://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/LRO/multimedia/lroimages/lroc-20110217-chain.html), but I think the breaking news is that a *new, different, not-collapsed sub-surface cave* has been identified.

---

**below:** Previously identified collapsed cave from [LRO imagery](https://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/LRO/multimedia/lroimages/lroc-20110217-chain.html), captioned:

> This section of WAC frame M117773324 shows the area where the feature transitions from a chain of collapse pits to a continuous uncollapsed segment. A large depression at the northern tip of the chain maybe a possible source region for the flow of lava across this region. The chain is approximately 50 km long. Image resolution 58.9 m/pixel [NASA/GSFC/Arizona State University].

[image]

Comment: Also [reported here](http://www.asahi.com/ajw/articles/AJ201710180045.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mission is SELENE (Kaguya), and they [used radar](http://www.asahi.com/ajw/articles/AJ201710180045.html) to detect a void under the surface:

> In 2009, the Kaguya probe found a large shaft with an opening about 50 meters in diameter in the Marius Hills area. The shaft descends about 50 meters beneath the surface.
>
> The JAXA team analyzed data obtained from a [lunar radar sounder](http://www.selene.jaxa.jp/en/equipment/lrs_e.htm) on the probe that indicated an underground structure extended west from the shaft.

LRS is the radar instrument:

> LRS is designed for sounding the surface and subsurface structures of the Moon by using HF radar technique with the frequency of 5 MHz. The low frequency radar method makes it possible to realize the mapping of the subsurface structure within a depth of several km with a range resolution of less than 100 m for a region with a horizontal scale of several tens of km.

Comment: 5 MHz radar! OK that makes sense for penetration. I wonder if the subsequent seven or eight years of analysis was necessary to fish out a small reflection from the rest of the geography; with a wavelength of 60 meters the signal must have been fairly isotropic and reflections were coming from all over the place. There's probably an interesting story. Thanks!

Comment: It hasn't made it to the English page yet: http://www.isas.jaxa.jp/topics/001156.html and here's the paper: http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/wol1/doi/10.1002/2017GL074998/abstract it looks like the text is not open access though.

Comment: I've just asked [What conditions could produce 50 km long lava tubes?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/12497/6031).